# How to not to override changes in specific directory when pushing to git repository?

Tags: git

Simply I have a git repository. And then directly on the server I just created `images` directory like this:

[image]

Now I push the changes from my local repository (there is no `images` directory), and `images` disappears. Why?

The question is:

**What to do to tell git to not to do anything with `images` directory?**

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you are trying to do. If you don't want to include something in a commit, don't `git add` it. If it's not in a commit, it consequently doesn't "overwrite" anything if you `git push`.

Comment: If the `images` directory is present in the upstream and not in your repository (and the upstream `HEAD` is a parent to your local `HEAD`), then the `images` directory was deleted sometime between those two commits and this deletion is applied to upstream.

Comment: To find out which commit did delete the `images` directory, try `git log "images/*"` (the quotes are required for the wildcard to be passed to git)

Answer (score 0):

Add the directory contents to a `.gitignore` file.

Either

```
images/*
```

in the project root or

```
*
!.gitignore
```

in the images directory.

Comment: This doesnt solve the problem because I need to change the content of this directory out of git.

Comment: That's fine, git should stop interfering with the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Git doesn't push *files*, Git pushes *commits*.  (Commits *contain* files: each commit has a full snapshot of *all* the files.)  The server that gets new commits then has to decide how *it* wants to deploy these new commits.  That part is up to the server, not up to you doing the `git push`.

> ... And then directly on the server I just created `images` directory ...

If—**if**—the server deploys a new commit by *completely removing the previous deployment* and then *completely installing the new commit*, then your `images` directory gets completely removed, and replaced with nothing.

If the server deploys a new commit in some other manner, something else happens to the `images` directory you created directly on the server.

This is not a function of Git, which is not a deployment system.  This is a function of whatever someone controlling the receiving Git *on* the server, programmed the server to do upon receiving new commits.  Find out who that "someone" is; find out what they did; find out what you should to do update it to behave whichever way you want it to.