# How to pull from git repository while replacing current files AND ignoring non-conflicting files

Tags: git

I have a website on my ubuntu server. I normally write the code on my laptop and then copy it over using scp. I decided I could just push to a git repository on my laptop and pull it on my server. My git repository on both machines is in /var/www/html (being served by apache2).

The problem:

> On my server, I have a symbolic link from /home/files to
>   /var/www/html/files. I also have a file
>   /var/www/html/images/image.png. This file and symbolic link don't
>   exist on my laptop, so when I do a git push from the laptop, they
>   don't get added to the repository.

I want:

> to do a git pull on my server and have it replace all the the current
>   webpages such as /var/www/html/home.php with the new version from the
>   repository, while not changing the local files that don't exist in the
>   repository such as /var/www/html/files/* and
>   /var/www/html/images/image.png

When I do a git pull on my server, git seems to replace the parent directory of /var/www/html/images/image.png (/var/www/html/images) and so I can't find /var/www/html/image.png

anymore.

What I did (on the laptop):

```
$ nano /var/www/html/home.php (update the webpage)

$ git push
```

What I did (on the server):

```
$ ln -s /home/files /var/www/html/files 
$ cp /home/some/random/image.png /var/www/html/images/image.png
$ git pull
```

I expected: to find a new version of /var/www/html/home.php and to still find the old /var/www/html/images/image.png

Instead: I found the new version of /var/www/html/home.php but no /var/www/html/images/image.png

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57178348/how-to-not-to-override-changes-in-specific-directory-when-pushing-to-git-reposit/57178728#57178728).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it: I had to add the files I want to remain untouched (namely images/image.png) to the gitignore file, then I did `git fetch --all` and then `git reset --hard origin/master`. This will update (and overwrite) all files in current directory to their new state on the remote repository (yes, this will overwrite any new changes you made, so remember to `git stash` if you don't want to lose your work). At the same time, any files in your `.gitignore` file will remain untouched :-). I wrote a little script: `git fetch --all && git reset --hard origin/master`.

Sources: The first answer here: [How do I force "git pull" to overwrite local files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125968/how-do-i-force-git-pull-to-overwrite-local-files)

Answer (score 0):

As Calum Halpin points links [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57178348/how-to-not-to-override-changes-in-specific-directory-when-pushing-to-git-reposit/57178728#57178728), you can easily create a file named `.gitignore` in the root of your repository that contains `images/image.png`.
With this, git does not track the image and won't delete it on your server.

You can also write a script that automatically pulls and creates the Symlink.

Comment: Okay, so you are saying that If I gitignore images/image.png, I can do a git pull and it will overwrite home.php but not images/image.png? What command can I use to make git overwrite current files with the newer version from the repository?

Comment: Git pull overwrites the files that changed with the newer version from the repository. After you added images/image.php git will ignore the image and won't overwrite it. So, the command is `git pull`.